# Joining large files into one humongous file

Tags: windows

Is there a way in Windows to link multiple files together without having to open the target file and read the contents of the source files to append them to the target file?  Something like a shell link api?

**Background**

I have up to 8 seperate processes creating parts of a data file that I want to recombine into one large file.

Comment: This goes well with [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560191/prepending-data-to-a-file) I just asked ~3 minutes ago I think. :)

Comment: This is not a programming-related question and should be moved to another forum.

Comment: it is a programming issue if there is an api for joining files that can be called from python or c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A less radical solution that should work just fine.

system("copy filefragment.1+filefragmenent.2+filefragment.3+....+filefragment.8 outputfile.bin");

Comment: This is what I went with.  Feels like cheating though.

Answer (score 1):

No simple way that I know of.  But here's a radical idea.

Use a virtual file system (Dokan, EldoS CBFS, Pismo Technic, etc..) to emulate one logical file that is actually backed by separate files on disk.

Comment: If only my organisation was open to radical ideas!

Answer (score 0):

> I have up to 8 seperate processes creating parts of a data file that I want to recombine into one large file.

```
How do you want them concatenated? Mixed or one after the other?
```

If you want them mixed, you can just open() your output file and write() to it from your threads. If you want them one after the other, you're best bet is to write to separate files and join them together at the end.